# How can I burn an ISO file to a blank disk?

Tags: software-recommendation, package-management, support

I have downloaded the Ubuntu 10.10 ISO file and am trying to burn it to a blank disc so that I can install it, using Ubuntu 8.04. I have a dual boot system with Windows and Ubuntu.

Here's my experience so far:

1. Boot up my current install of Hardy Heron
2. Go to install updates. Click on Check and informed that 8.10 is available. Firstly install any other updates.
3. Click on Upgrage, get error 'Could not find release notes'
4. Manually download entire 10.10 image from the internet
5. Attempt to burn to disc using Brasero.
6. Burn fails
7. Can no longer mount any discs
8. Restart
9. Can no longer mount any blank discs, but can mount audio discs
10. Restart, now I can mount blank disks
11. Right click on .iso image and choose "Open with CD/DVD creator"
12. Attempt to burn image to disk
13. Wait 20 minutes while disc is apparently burning, for some reason when it is finished it is still blank
14. Attempt to burn again with Brasero, burn completes. Asks me to reenter disk for checksum. Checksum check freezes after 10 minutes. I attempt to eject disk and it tells me 100% success.
15. After restarting from newly burned CD it shows me a screen with Ubuntu and 5 dots, it stays like that for 10 minutes and then eventually I get an error cannot mount disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** - Re brasero failed:

I don't know why it is not working, but the version of Ubuntu you are currently using is very old and no longer supported so don't take this experience as representative of the present.

You state that you have Windows installed, so you could try to burn the image using your Windows installation:

- Download and install [Infra Recorder](http://infrarecorder.org/), a free and open-source image-burning program.
- Insert a blank CD in the drive and select Do nothing or Cancel if an autorun dialog box pops up.
- Open Infra Recorder and click the 'Write Image' button in the main screen.
- Alternatively you can select the 'Actions' menu, then 'Burn image'.
- Select the Ubuntu CD image file you want to use, then click 'Open'.
- In the dialog box, click 'OK'.

[image: Infra Recorder]

---

You should be able to just right click on the disk image and click 'Write to Disc...'. I don't know if that option was available in 8.04.

If not, use Brasero. Make sure the [brasero](http://packages.ubuntu.com/brasero) package is installed (you can install it using Synaptic).

Open Brasero from the Applications->Sound and Video menu and choose 'Burn image'.

[image: Brasero]

You should then be able to select the image file and chose a disc to burn it to:

[image: burn disc]

For more instructions check out [step 2 of this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download) and click the 'Show me how' button, selecting which platform you want to use to burn the disc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've got it burned now, but the burned disc still doesn't work :(

Comment: This is either an error with the burning of the disc or Ubuntu is having problems with your hardware. Try running the [CD Integrity check](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck?action=show&redirect=CDIntegrityCheck) from the live CD to see if all of the files are intact. If it is OK, you should probably ask a new question about how to install Ubuntu - make sure you include details about the hardware you are installing on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I reburned the disk and it worked (a little too well as you've seen in my other question http://askubuntu.com/questions/25436/have-i-lost-my-entire-windows-drive-and-all-the-files).

Answer (score 2):

**To put the application on the Menu list**: right click on Application->edit menu-> sound & video check the application you want to display in the application  drop down menu.

**burning software** i recommend "K3b"  you can put k3b in the application menu like the first one. or the other option is run the application using terminal open terminal write K3b.

Comment: But neither K3b or Nautilus appear in that menu, how do I add them to that menu?

Comment: it will publish in the menu list automatically  if you check the application checkbox on the application edit menu.

Comment: There is no Application -> edit menu on my system.

Comment: **Right-click** on "Application" Menu, then click on "edit menu"

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to burn a downloaded, Ubuntu operating system iso file to a blank CD is not to use Brasero, it never seems to work and always tells me that my blank disc has insufficient space.

I use GnomeBaker CD Writer/Burner, which can be installed from Ubuntu Download Centre.
After opening GnomeBaker be careful NOT to select one of the three tabs in the 'Make new project' section - otherwise you will just copy the iso file. You need to go to 'Tools' in the top menu bar and select 'Burn CD Image' - that way you will get all the other files that you need to install your new version of Ubuntu.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

The standard program for burning iso's in ubuntu is Brasero found in the sound menu. I am not sure if this is available on 8.04 but equally I don't think nautalus can burn iso's either.