# My Hard drives are gone

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive

i just replaced windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC but it formated the C drive which had the Windows 7 in it, and now Ubuntu is installed and is fully working, but none of my Hard drives are there anymore, both of them were there at the trial

All my folders stored in it were there, but now they don't show anymore. I can't afford to lose them

Answer (score 1):

This happens. If you formatted your drive in which the data was there, then you will have to try and recover it using a recovery software. I recommend testdisk (sudo apt-get install testdisk). It is a command line utility but very powerful. You will have to run it on the partition/drive you had your data on and see if it can recover your data.

If yo haven't formatted your drive, well, that case is trivial. You do "sudo fdisk -l", try mounting the partitions that it shows and check whether the data is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Disk Utility

You can try looking for the disks via the "Disk Utility" ( should already installed on your system ).

#### How to..

If you open the Unity Dash ( Windows Key ), then type in "Disk Utility". This will allow you to check all the disks your system knows about and give you a handy "Mount" button for each

Comment: If Disk Utility does not work,Insert a Windows Installation Disk, and go upto where it shows the Drive format option, If you can see your other drives, then format the C:/ with Windows  (Reinstall windows on C). Then you might get your files back. (Its a theory, I never used this though).

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you are not confusing Physical Hard Disk Drive with Partitions.

Assuming that you have 2 or more HDD's and if your hard disk drives seems not to be shown on your file browser, maybe they are unmounted or disconnected.

But having in consideration that all the people is assuming that you erased your partitions when installing, then: yes... you are in the need to start data recovery and probably forensic procedures to do it.

I suggest you to run a search on this site with the words: "data recovery" (without quotation marks) and take a look at the previous experiences by other users.

I also advice you to see this questions in detail, which seems to be working for some users: [How to recover Deleted Files and Folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33800/how-to-recover-deleted-files-and-folders) and [How can I recover data from a 2TB hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53902/how-can-i-recover-data-from-a-2tb-hard-drive).

You may also wish to take a look at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery which contains detailed procedures for recovering lost data.

You need to stay calm and stop working on your computer. The more you do with the computer is the more risk you expose your data. So please use a different computer to find information and if possible, use a live session for the recovery.

I am following your question closely in order to help you. Please let us know how are you managing this issue.

Good luck!