# Ubuntu Tools for recovering data from damaged USB Flash Drive ~ 10 Gb

Tags: usb-drive, data-recovery

I have technical issues with my USB Flash Drive - JetFlash®V15 (TS16GJFV15)
It's very critical situation because I can not see the data from it and I should get a way to recover them ASAP.

So, in general, I have connected Non-stop that USB Flash Disk at my laptop.
Was appear Power surges and when I was coming back, I saw that problem with it.

Details regarding JetFlash®V15 (in present):
 - when I connect it on USP slot, the led is working intermittent and later on remain with constant light.
 - if I inspect the computer drivers, I found "Generic USB Flash Disk" (when the stick it's connected).
 - if I inspect "Properties", I can see next details:
   --- Type: unknown (application/octet-stream)
   --- Size: unknown
   --- Volume: unknown
   --- Accessed: unknown
   --- Modified: unknown

I inspected that stick on 2 different computers (as well in different different USB Ports) and was the same problem, I can not see the content.
I was checking with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 OS, but without success.
With both OS was working before this issue.

I'll appreciate an answer which will solve the problem, not an answer which will certify the problem.

What I have to do, to recover the information form it (nearly 10 Gb)?
I'm looking forward to be guided from a technical expert.

Comment: In case its only a partition/format issue see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/31450/tool-for-recovering-deleted-data-from-a-flash-drive. You can also try recovery from a bit-by-bit image as shown here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53902/how-can-i-recover-data-from-a-2tb-hard-drive.

Comment: It sounds like the partition table is corrrupted. I would try testdisk... be careful to follow the instructions very closely. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Answer (score 1):

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/recoverdeletedfiles/ 
Explains with great ease and great pictures too

Answer (score 1):

If no tool can read the USB stick, a last ditch effort is to carefully pull the stick apart and hope that the actual memory is on a micro-SD card.  Sometimes the reader-electronics on the stick fails, making the stick useless, but the memory is actually OK, if you can get to it. Read the card with any card reader. I successfully did this with a 4G USB, so worth a try before throwing the stick away.