# Possible bad hard disk recovery

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, badblocks

My friend had some important files on an internal HDD, and asked for help after his laptop suddenly freezed, restarted and won't boot again on Windows. HDD was still listed in BIOS.

In Windows, if i try to connect it via an external rack explorer is very unresponsive.

Trying to mount in Ubuntu, but with no success.

I've tried some commands found on the web. Here are the outputs:

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

> UUID=d4762b01-e847-4ebb-aa14-4d26ac75db04 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

So /dev/sdb it won't show up, as expected.

```
dmesg | grep sdb
```

> [  899.236716]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb4 sdb5
>
> [  899.237396] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
>
> [  899.237403] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
>
> [  899.237438] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
>
> [  901.209031] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
>
> [  901.210836] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
>
> [  901.210844] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
>
> [  901.213923] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
>
> [  928.306294] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
>
> [  928.306300] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3a 38 60 28 00 00 01 00
>
> [  928.306303] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 976773160
>
> [  928.306311] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 122096645, async page read

So it seems that there are some errors with the HDD.

```
ls /dev/sd*
```

It shows `/dev/sdb` but that's it.

Tried `testdisk` but it won't show up in selection screen.
In my opinion it seems like a really messed up filesystem. So, to sum it up, HDD shows up without partitions and in Ubuntu Disks it shows up as `Block device` with 0GB size and no info, and sometimes it won't show up.
I can check the SMART attributes but it seems that it's nothing wrong there.

The recovery of files is a plus, but it's optional.

**Thank you!**

Comment: I use a external enclosure, another hard disk works perfectly, so, the cables are ok.

Comment: kk - then, to avoid further damage (in case the drive is physically damaged) try to recover from a disk image. See e.g.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/53902/how-can-i-recover-data-from-a-2tb-hard-drive and https://askubuntu.com/questions/425518/recover-files-from-a-broken-virtualbox-machine-vdi - and more