# Guest account files

Tags: guest-session

My houseguest just wrote a 20 page paper using the guest account on my computer. We saved it and she logged out. Is that paper gone? We haven't rebooted.

I'm going to feel really, really horrible if this is gone!

I logged her out so I could try to troubleshoot the fact that her thumb drive isn't mounting.

I don't see anything in `/tmp` that looks like the guest file.

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224826/ubuntu-deleted-files-from-guest-account-desktop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Google and found this:

[Guest Session File Recovery](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1630613)

So now you probably need this:

[data-recovery-software-for-windows-linux-platform](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53073/data-recovery-software-for-windows-linux-platform)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm still floored by this, but she retyped her paper.